# Is it possible to change cx, cy and r of a SVG circle during print?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, lit-element

I have this svg circle:

```xml
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5"/>
</svg>
```

I would like to reduce the circle dimension if I print the webpage.

Does it exist a way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

When I say "print" I mean both print pdf of the page and print the page on a paper sheet.

**EDIT #2**

This is what I tried with @media print.

```
@media print {
          circle{
            height: 0.8vw;
            width: 0.8vw;
          }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can edit the attributes of an SVG in real-time.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Can you explain me how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: use a CSS media query to change the values. I.e. @media print

Comment: I tried to change width and height inside a @media print query, but nothing changed...

Comment: Edit the question to show us what you did with the media query. Note that you may need to set all values via CSS rather than by attributes.

Comment: You could try this: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-svg-with-media-queries/

Comment: Why not just have two circles, and show or hide each one with a print media query?

Comment: I think that you'll need to specify the normal circle values via CSS as well as the print values otherwise the media query can't override them.

Comment: Why not changing the size of the svg element?

Answer (score 2):

You can alter SVG attributes with Lit:

```
const radius = 5;
svg`<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10">
  <circle id="circle" cx=${radius} cy=${radius} r=${radius}/>
</svg>`
```

You can also set SVG shape properties with CSS variables:

```css
:host {
    --prefix-radius: 10;
}

#circle {
    cy: var(--prefix-radius);
    cx: var(--prefix-radius);
    r: var(--prefix-radius);
}

@media print {
    #circle{
        --prefix-radius: 5;
    }
}
```

You can scale the entire SVG:

```css
@media print {
    svg.shrinkOnPrint {
        height: 0.8vw;
        width: 0.8vw;
    }
}
```

Finally you can have multiple versions and only show the relevant one:

```css
svg.forPrintOnly { display: none; }

@media print {
    svg:not(.forPrint) { display: none; }
    svg.forPrintOnly {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

```html
<svg>                      <!-- appears on screen but not print -->
<svg class="forPrint">     <!-- appears on screen & print -->
<svg class="forPrintOnly"> <!-- only show on print -->
```